# python Printing a list in a tabular format without modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list called `entryList` which begins empty, but as the user is prompted for input this input is added to the list. After 2 runs the list will look something like this:
`[2, 1234, 'E', 2.0, 2.71, 6, 0800, 'U', 2.34, 20.89]`
with each iteration of asking for input adding 5 values to the list. When this list is printed, I need it to look something like this:

```
EntryNo  PumpNo  Time  FType  LPrice  FAmount
---------------------------------------------
1        2       1234  E      2.00    2.71 
2        6       0800  U      2.34    20.89
```

How can I get the list to print like this, with the EntryNo column increasing by 1 for each new row added, without importing any modules?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: i haven't tried anything because i have no clue how to even start

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow is not a "code for me" site. You must show an attempt you have made from your side, if you face any problem or get stuck then community can help you

Comment: apologies, i was unaware

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### With some print and some formatting

```
values = [2, '1234', 'E', 2.0, 2.71,
          6, '0800', 'U', 2.34, 20.89]

cols = ["EntryNo", "PumpNo", "Time", "FType", "LPrice", "FAmount"]
print(*cols)
print("-" * len(" ".join(cols)))  # optional

for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, len(values), 5), start=1):
    print("{:<7d} {:<6d} {:<4s} {:<5s} {:<6.2f} {} ".format(idx, *values[i:i + 5]))
```

```
EntryNo PumpNo Time FType LPrice FAmount
----------------------------------------
1       2      1234 E     2.00   2.71 
2       6      0800 U     2.34   20.89
```

---

#### With module `pandas`

You can use pandas, you'll easily have an nice output, with `to_markdown` for example

```
import pandas as pd

values = [2, '1234', 'E', 2.0, 2.71,
          6, '0800', 'U', 2.34, 20.89]

df = pd.DataFrame([[idx, *values[i:i + 5]] for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, len(values), 5), start=1)],
                  columns=["EntryNo", "PumpNo", "Time", "FType", "LPrice", "FAmount"])

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

```
|   EntryNo |   PumpNo |   Time | FType   |   LPrice |   FAmount |
|----------:|---------:|-------:|:--------|---------:|----------:|
|         1 |        2 |   1234 | E       |     2    |      2.71 |
|         2 |        6 |   0800 | U       |     2.34 |     20.89 |
```

Comment: unfortunately as i said i can't import modules